# lerping each value of two arrays of the same size in P5.js

Tags: p5.js

i am trying to make a bezier curve that changes smoothly every time i click. I am trying to lerp the values of one array with another array of the same size.

```
 for(let i = 0; i < OldBezierX.length; i ++){
    OldBezierX[i] = floor(lerp(OldBezierX[i] , NewBezierX[i] , 0.1));
    OldBezierY[i] = floor(lerp(OldBezierY[i] , NewBezierY[i] , 0.1));
  }
```

this is my best attempt but i cant seem to make it work.

Comment: any joy with the answer bellow ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are lerping by the same amount: `0.1` which means the result always be 10% of the way transitioned between the old and the new.

It might be worth using a third couple of arrays to store the result so your old and new arrays remain intact. Assuming you have another couple of lists called `lerpedBezierX` and `lerpedBezierY` and a variable `t` you to store the interpolation amount:

```
for(let i = 0; i < OldBezierX.length; i ++){
    lerpedBezierX[i] = lerp(OldBezierX[i] , NewBezierX[i] , t);
    lerpedBezierY[i] = lerp(OldBezierY[i] , NewBezierY[i] , t);
  }
```

on click you would increment `t` from 0.0 to 1.0.

Also, it's unclear why it's necessary to `floor()` the `lerp()` result

Comment: Thank you for spotting the error in my answer :) It was not a valid answer and I've deleted it.